# Debian - How to save variable in a text file / Zenity

Tags: debian, zenity

I create with Zenity a small form to input some text (Here a gateway for a network). I want to save the result of this entry in a text file tu re-use in another form.

[image: here is my form]

I hope you will understood, thank's for all

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this line :

```
echo $Passerelle > yourfile
```